# Python composition: Getting an attribute error for object inside the class

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 64, in <module>
    set_airline = reservation.obj_flight.set_airline_name('United')
AttributeError: 'Reservation' object has no attribute 'obj_flight'
```

The main code:

```
class Airlines:
    def init__(self,airline_name):
      self.__name_airline = airline_name

    def set_airline_name(self,airline_name):
      self.__name_airline = airline_name

    def get_airline_name(self):
      return self.__name_airline


class Flight(Airlines):
  def __init_(self,airline_name,flight_number):
    super().__init__(airline_name)
    self.__flight_number = flight_number

  def set_flight_number(self,flight_number):
    self.__flight_number = flight_number

  def get_flight_number(self):
    return self.__flight_number

class Customer:
  def __init_(self,cust_name,cust_id):
    self.__cust_name = cust_name
    self.__cust_id = cust_id

  def set_cust_name(self,cust_name):
    self.__cust_name = cust_name

  def get_cust_name(self):
    return self.__cust_name

  def set_cust_id(self,cust_id):
    self.cust_id = cust_id

  def get_cust_id(self):
    return self.__cust_id

class Reservation:
  def __init_(self,airline_name,flight_number,cust_name,cust_id):
    self.__reservation_date = ""
    self.__reservation_time = ""
    self.obj_flight = Flight(airline_name,flight_number)
    self.obj_customer = Customer(cust_name,cust_id)

  def set_reservation_date(self,reservation_date):
      self.__reservation_date = reservation_date

  def set_reservation_time(self,reservation_time):
      self.__reservation_time = reservation_time

  def get_reservation_date(self):
      return self.__reservation_date

  def get_reservation_time(self):
      return self.__reservation_time

reservation = Reservation()

set_res_date = reservation.set_reservation_date('04-05-2019')
set_res_time = reservation.set_reservation_time('3:45')

set_airline = reservation.obj_flight.set_airline_name('United')
set_flight_number = reservation.obj_flight.set_flight_number(2043)
set_customer_name = reservation.obj_customer.set_cust_name('Adam Smith')
customer_id = reservation.obj_customer.set_cust_id(345)

get_airline = reservation.obj_flight.get_airline_name()
get_flight_number = reservation.obj_flight.get_flight_number()
get_customer_name = reservation.obj_customer.get_cust_name()
get_customer_id = reservation.obj_customer.get_cust_id

reserv_date = reservation.get_reservation_date()
reserv_time = reservation.get_reservation_time()
print(get_customer_name,get_airline,get_flight_number,reserv_date,reserv_time)
```

I tried to use composition in the Class Reservation to incorporate Classes Flight and Customer. I have the object flight and customer in the Reservation Class but it's not finding it. The IDLE is suggesting that reservation has obj_flight and obj_customer. Also, when I tried to plug in arguments in Reservation() at first, it was giving me an error that it doesn't accept any position arguments. Hence, I am setting each attribute separately.

Comment: You have a typo in `Reservation`: `def __init_` needs to be `def __init__`. Your constructor is never running.

Comment: Good eye @Carcigenicate — I was staring at this an could see nothing.

Comment: @MarkMeyer It's from a long history of seeing that exact typo. The pattern is the behavior doesn't make sense assuming the constructor is running. The answer is always just that the constructor isn't running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing one underscore on the `__init__` function, all your `__init__` functions are not well declared actually, it needs two underscores before, and two after. Your program is probably not processing the object constructor and its creating the default `__init__` method by himself, which is:

```py
def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Thats why the line where you instantiate `Reservation` does not raise and error for not passing constructor arguments:

```py
# This should raise TypeError: Missing x arguments....
reservation = Reservation()
```

Final result should be:

```py
def __init__(self,airline_name,flight_number,cust_name,cust_id):
    self.__reservation_date = ""
    self.__reservation_time = ""
    self.obj_flight = Flight(airline_name,flight_number)
    self.obj_customer = Customer(cust_name,cust_id)
```

### Additional info

You are inheriting classes in your code, notice that if you use type mangling (double `_` before an attribute), does not allow the property to be inherited.

Comment: I am getting this error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 59, in <module>
    reservation = Reservation('United',2043,'Adam Smith',345,'5:00','04-05-2019')
  File "main.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.obj_flight = Flight(airline_name,flight_number)
TypeError: Flight() takes no arguments`

Comment: As I said, you have fix all `__init__`  methods syntax. Flight class' one is not correct.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed all the __init__ and it's now working. Thanks.

Comment: Would appreciate if you could validate the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because there is a typo in the constructor funnction: `__init_` instead `__init__` and because of that, the attributes are not initialized.